# Сreating one python dictionary from several

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I'm trying to make one dictionary out of three, but of two different types. Type one, if all the keys matched I want to get a dictionary of type templ_ip_parameters_1. And if the keys matched only in the dictionaries dict_1 and dict_3 I want to get a dictionary of type templ_ip_parameters_2. When I execute the code I get a `KeyError`, because the key 'GigabitEthernet0/0/0' does not match. Help me write a proper loop. Thank you!

```
dict_1 = {
'GigabitEthernet0/0/0': '1.1.1.1/31',
'GigabitEthernet0/0/2': '2.2.2.2/31',
'GigabitEthernet0/0/1.2': '3.3.3.3/31', 
}

dict_2 = {
'GigabitEthernet0/0/1': 'test_2', 
'GigabitEthernet0/0/2': 'test_1', 
'GigabitEthernet0/0/1.6': 'test_3', 
}

dict_3 = {
'GigabitEthernet0/0/0': 891,
'GigabitEthernet0/0/2': 892,
'GigabitEthernet0/0/1.2': 893, 
'GigabitEthernet0/0/1.5': 894, 
}

#templ_ip_parameters_1 = {
#"address": '',
#"vrf": {"name": ""},
#"assigned_object_id": None,

#templ_ip_parameters_2 = {
#"address": '',
#"assigned_object_id": None,

templ_ip_parameters_1 = {}


for interface in dict_1.keys():
    if dict_2[interface]:
        templ_ip_parameters_1 = dict(address = '', assigned_object_id = None)
        templ_ip_parameters_1['address'] = dict_1[interface]
        templ_ip_parameters_1['assigned_object_id'] = dict_3[interface]
    if dict_3[interface]:
        templ_ip_parameters_1 = dict(address = '', vrf = {"name": ""}, assigned_object_id = None)
        templ_ip_parameters_1['address'] = dict_1[interface]
        templ_ip_parameters_1['vrf']['name'] = dict_2[interface]
        templ_ip_parameters_1['assigned_object_id'] = dict_3[interface]
        print(templ_ip_parameters_1)
```

Comment: If you can isolate the exact problem you are having and build a minimalist example out of it (maybe using `a`, `b`,  and `c` or `1`, `2`, `3` etc..) your chance of getting an answer improves dramatically.

Comment: Also, do you really need those comments in your code to make your question as clear as possible for a volunteer to help you?

Comment: @lucascavalcante I would like to get a templ_ip_parameters_1 dictionary of two different types. One type when there is a keys match in all dictionaries, example templ_ip_parameters_1 = {
"address": '2.2.2.2/31',
{ "vrf": { "name": "test_1"},
"assigned_object_id": 892,

The second type, when there are matching keys only in dict_1 and dict_3, example 
 templ_ip_parameters_1 = {"address": '1.1.1.1/31',"assigned_object_id": 891}
 templip_ip_parameters_1 = {"address": '3.3.3.3/31',"assigned_object_id": 893}

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
templ_ip_parameters_1 = []
for interface in dict_1.keys():
        if interface in dict_2 and interface in dict_3:
            res = dict(address='', vrf={"name": ""}, assigned_object_id=None)
            res['address'] = dict_1[interface]
            res['vrf']['name'] = dict_2[interface]
            res['assigned_object_id'] = dict_3[interface]
            templ_ip_parameters_1.append(res)
        elif interface in dict_3:
            res = dict(address='', assigned_object_id=None)
            res['address'] = dict_1[interface]
            res['assigned_object_id'] = dict_3[interface]
            templ_ip_parameters_1.append(res)
    print (templ_ip_parameters_1)
```

Comment: Great! Doc Thank you! You're a big help!